# Where is that best reference to compare Hibernate and Active Record?

Tags: database, hibernate, architecture, activerecord

I like Active Record but many say it's bad in performance compared to Hibernate. There should be some good article out there but google can't help me.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is to compare [Active Record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) (Rails) and [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) (Hibernate), the 'Data Source Architectural Patterns' chapter from [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) is a good place to start.

It explains clearly the concepts behind these patterns and when to use each one, but doesn't discuss specific implementations like Rails or Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean? Active Record is a design pattern and Hibernate is a framework.

Do you mean comparing rails to hibernate w/java?

Comment: I mean concept of Active Record compare to concept of Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

I think he refers to NHibernate and Castle ActiveRecord.
Castle ActiveRecord is built upon NHibernate, and should result in similar performance.